# Doubt about superposition principle

Tags: optics, waves, superposition

[image]The superposition position in waves is defined as 'the total displacement produced equals vector sum of individual waves.Given that 2 sources S1 and S2 produce waves who's displacement are y1 and y2 both equal to acosωt, won't the resultant vector be √(a^2+b^2+2abcosωt)= $\sqrt{2A^2\cos^2 \omega t + 2A^2\cos^3\omega t}$ instead of resultant being acosωt+acosωt= 2acosωt where a and b are amplitude of the two displacements y1 and y2. Assume a=b.

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, $\theta$? And what are you computing? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I already mentioned that a and b are amplitudes of 2 different waves. θ would naturally mean the smaller angle between vectors. I will improve my question.

Comment: Angle between what vectors?

Comment: Angle between the phases of waves -ωt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression for the resultant amplitude is correct, but it's not in the simplest form.

$$\sqrt{2a^2 +2a^2\cos \theta}=\sqrt{2a^2(1+\cos \theta)}=\sqrt{2a^2(c^2+s^2+c^2-s^2)}=2ac$$
$$\text{in which}\ \ \ \ c=\cos \left(\tfrac{\theta}2\right),\ s=\sin \left(\tfrac{\theta}2\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll improve my trigonometry.

Comment: @PhilipWood It is the $a\cos θ+a\cos θ= 2a\cos θ$ which is incorrect.

Comment: @Farcher Yes indeed, but the expression with the square root was the OP's expression, and that *is* correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is the $a\cos θ+a\cos θ= 2a\cos θ$ which is incorrect.

In the other derivation you have the phase difference between the two waves as $\theta$ so you need either to evaluate the resultant of two phasors each with  amplitude $a$ and a phase difference of $\theta$ between them.

[image]

The result of the addition is $2a\cos(\theta/2)$ not $2a\cos(\theta)$.

For the other method which uses the cosine rule the important trig relationship is $1+\cos \theta = 2 \cos^2(\theta/2)$